# hover not working in jquery ui <a href="javascript: submitform()">Country</a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, hyperlink, href

I am using **jquery ui**

when I write the following code , hover working

```
<a href="genCountryInq.htm">Country</a>
```

but as I change the following then , hover not working

```
<form id="linkform" action="genCountryInq.htm" method="post">
    <a href="javascript: submitform()">Country</a>
</form>
```

and the same case here

```
<form id="linkform" action="genCountryInq.htm" method="post">
     <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Country</a>
</form>
```

**Update me !**

Comment: For the last one , have you included the jQuery library file?

Comment: Then it should work for second one.

Comment: What do you mean by *hover* not working? Is this a styling issue?

Comment: yes! styling issue ! now ok !

Comment: If you're still having issues with this, can you include your CSS code as well?

Comment: @jcsanyi its ok now ! thanks for coordination !

Answer (score 2):

For your first option, you need to either define the `submitform` function like:

```
function submitform() {
    document.getElementById('linkform').submit();
}
```

OR

You can use:

```
<a href="javascript: document.getElementById('linkform').submit();">Country</a>.
```

And for your second option if you have included the `jQuery` library file it works as expected.